# c += map(lambda n: n *2, c) kills the Python 3 shell. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = [1, 2]
>>> c += map(lambda n: n *2, range(1, 3))
>>> c
[1, 2, 2, 4]
>>> c = [1, 2]
>>> c += map(lambda n: n *2, c)
Killed!
```

However the same works with Python 2 where map results in a list unlike a generator in Python 3. Then why does `c += map(lambda n: n *2, range(1, 3))` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`c += foo` does the equivalent of `c = c.__iadd__(foo)`. And if `c` is a list, the `list.__iadd__` method accepts any iterable, including a generator expression:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x += (i for i in range(3))
>>> x
[0, 1, 2]
```

this even though `list.__add__` does *not* support generator expressions:

```
>>> x + (i for i in range(3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list
```

---

The code crashes in Python 3 because the `map` generator iterates over the *same* list that is being extended, but the current position is always two elements behind the tail. The `list.__iadd__` will always add new elements to the end one by one as they are extracted from the iterator; as this happens, the index used by the list iterator held by the `map` generator will be incremented... but a new element was added to the end of the list so there are always 2 elements after the current iteration position, and eventually Python runs out of memory or the computer grinds to halt due to swapping.

I.e. the behaviour is not unlike that of

```
for elem in c:
    c.append(elem * 2)
```

(kudos to [Wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim))

The Python 2 version works exactly because `map` will create a list *before* calling `c.__iadd__`; a new list of 2 elements will be passed to `c.__iadd__`. Likewise the `c += map(lambda n: n * 2, range(1, 3))` would work because in Python 2 `range(1, 3)` would create a *new list*, and in Python 3 it would create a range sequence object, and both of them are distinct

If you replace the `map` with a generator expression, you can trigger pathological behaviour in Python 2 too:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> x += (n * 2 for n in x)
```